# crystal report Arabic language encrypted when printing?

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports-2008

crystal report Arabic language encrypted  when printing
[image]

Comment: what do you need exactly?

Comment: @Siva correct Arabic Displaying ( why language encrypted ) ?!

Comment: from where are you getting arabic data?

Comment: i am making textField TextObject and report source data contain Arabic 
all encrypted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Arabic Language or Change your system Language To Arabic !